# Webstorm debug not work

Tags: webstorm, sapui5

I'm trying to configure Webstorm to work in debug-mode with chrome extension jetbrains IDE Support. 
I want start with this app https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/poa/index.html

I download the sdk https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/poa/index.html and I take `\test-resources\sap\m\demokit\poa` folder and import it in webstorm by "New Project from Existing Files..." and then I select this Scenario [image]

I have installed the jetbrains IDE Support plugin in Chrome. Now, if I run the index.html all **work fine**!
But if I debug the file I have this result...:
[image]

This is my index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>UI5 Boilerplate</title>

    <!-- UI5 Bootstrap with OpenUI5 -->
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            type="text/javascript"
            src="resources/openui/sap-ui-core-dbg.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
            "ui5bp": "./",
            "model": "./model"
             }'
        >
    </script>


    <!-- Custom Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

   <script>

        new sap.m.Shell("Shell", {
            showLogout : false,
            app : new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                name : 'ui5bp'
            }),
            homeIcon : {
                'phone' : 'img/57_iPhone_Desktop_Launch.png',
                'phone@2' : 'img/114_iPhone-Retina_Web_Clip.png',
                'tablet' : 'img/72_iPad_Desktop_Launch.png',
                'tablet@2' : 'img/144_iPad_Retina_Web_Clip.png',
                'favicon' : 'img/favicon.ico',
                'precomposed': false
            }
        }).placeAt('root');
   </script>
</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" id="root">
</body>

</html>
```

and this is the output of console in Webstorm whe the page show me "waiting from localhost...":

```
2014-12-30 14:50:16 Device API logging initialized - DEVICE
2014-12-30 14:50:16 SAP Logger started. -  
2014-12-30 14:50:16 registerResourcePath ('', 'resources/openui/') -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem
2014-12-30 14:50:16 registerResourcePath ('ui5bp', './') -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem
2014-12-30 14:50:16 registerResourcePath ('model', './model/') -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem
2014-12-30 14:50:16 URL prefixes set to: -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem
2014-12-30 14:50:16   (default) : resources/openui/ -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem
2014-12-30 14:50:16   'ui5bp' : ./ -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem
2014-12-30 14:50:16   'model' : ./model/ -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem
```

where am I wrong?

Comment: At home this procedure works fine, but at work I have this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now works fine! I set this options:
[image]